# Can't see any changes in website after i changed the logo while using dokcer

Tags: php, html, docker, github

Im new to docker and learning it for a job interview and was given a task
the last step in the task was to clone a repo in github to my computer
then to fire it up which i did by right click on the project folder in my computer then "open with powershell" then entered  `docker compose pull` and then `docker-compose up`
and when went to localhost:8080 and i can see the website page.
i was asked to change the logo in that website so what i did is-
i went inside the project folder until i found the logo that is being used and what i did is i changed it to a different photo that i found and kept the name the same.
after firing up the webpage again using $ docker-compose up the page is still showing the old logo and is not taking the one i put in the project folder.
is this something you can help with?
Thanks
Tal

Comment: Try docker-compose up --build, i guess the code is copied during build and not mounted

Comment: You need to first figure out how the project you are building works. Check with your peers or take a KT about it. Once that is done, you can check the docker-compose documents to see how can you rebuild the project with your changes.

Answer (score 0):

By executing **docker-compose up** will  builds the images if the images do not exist and starts the containers. If you add the **--build** option, it is forced to build the images even when not needed. Since you have done code changes, you must rebuild it.

```
 docker-compose up --build
```